# Congruent sets of an arithmetic sequence and a geometric sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, quadratics, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Suppose we have a $a,d,$ and $q$ such that $a \neq 0, d \neq 0.$ Then, let $M = \{a, a + d, a + 2d\}$ and $N = \{a, aq, aq^2\}.$ Given that $M = N,$ find the value of $q.$

(A) $\frac12$

(B) $\frac13$

(C) $-\frac14$

(D) $-\frac12$

(E) $-2$

---

I immediately thought about setting $a + d = aq$ and $a + 2d = aq^2.$ I then proceeded to do $aq^2 - aq = d,$ and substitute in for $d,$ which gave me $a + (aq^2 - aq) = aq.$ Simplifying then gave me $aq^2 - 2aq + a = 0,$ and dividing by $a$ gave me $q^2 - 2q + 1 = 0,$ which should mean that $q = 1.$ However, that's not an answer choice. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have three cases.

1. $$2aq=a+aq^2$$ or $$q=1,$$ which is impossible because $d\neq0$.
2. $$2aq^2=a+aq$$ or
   $$2q^2-q-1=0,$$ which gives $$q=-\frac{1}{2}.$$
3. $$2a=aq+aq^2.$$
   Can you end it now?

Comment: Ah, I see how to do it now. Thank you!

Comment: @questionasker You are welcome!

Comment: Actually the third case is immediately impossible because $a$ and $a$ must be equal in the two sets and hence $a$ must be the smallest or the largest element in the geometric set as well.

Comment: @cr001 The third case gives $q=-2$. No? So $d=3a$.

Comment: $q=-2$ does not match the first set and must be discarded. In $(a,a+d,a+2d)$, $a$ must be either the largest or the smallest. It cannot be the average of the other two.

Comment: @cr001  For $q=-2$ we have $-2a,a,4a$ is an arithmetic progression and $a,-2a,4a$ is a geometric progression. No? We just say about sets.

Comment: $(-2a,a,4a)$ cannot be expressed as $(a,a+d,a+2d)$

Comment: @cr001  We say about sets. See please better the given.$(a,a+d,a+2d)$ and $\{a,a+d,a+2d\}$ they are different things.

Comment: The point is that $(a,a+d,a+2d)$ is a stricter condition than "an arithmetic sequence including $a$". It has the additional constraint that $a$ must be either the largest or the smallest.

Comment: Yes it is about sets without order. There is no $d$ that can make the set $a,a+d,a+2d$ equal to $-2a,a,4a$ no matter what the order you let it be.

Comment: I am talking about the set {a,a+d,a+2d} I used the () bracket because {} will disappear in latex notation. I did not mean ordered set.

Comment: @cr001 Wow! You are right! Thank you! But I did not write it in my post, otherwise, it would be my mistake. Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Surely $q=1$ would mean that $d=0$, which is precluded by the conditions of your problem.

Have you considered that $M=N$  means only that the elements are the same, but does not imply anything about *in which ordering*. What you have proven is that the ordering you've attempted doesn't work.

Let's try adifferent ordering. Due to $d\ne 0$, $M$ and $N$ both consist of three different numbers, and $a$ is common in both. Thus, you have only two possibilities for the ordering. One is the one you've examined ($a+d=aq, a+2d=aq^2$), and the other is: $a+d=aq^2, a+2d=aq$. Now, applying the same logic as you did, but to *this* ordering, you get: $$a(2q^2-q-1)=0$$ which, after cancelling $a$ ($a\ne 0$) and solving for $q$ gives you the solutions $q=1$ or $q=-1/2$. The first solution is forbidden, so we are left with $q=-1/2$ (answer D).

One example is $4, 1, -2$ (arithmetic progression) vs. $4,-2,1$ (geometric progression).

Answer (score 0):

One could also work with the difference between terms, rather than eliminating it.  The two possible orderings of the elements in the set are
$ \ \{ a \ , \ aq \ = \ a + d \ , \ aq^2 \ = \ a + 2d \}  \ $ or $ \ \{ a \ , \ aq \ = \ a + 2d \ , \ aq^2 \ = \ a + d \}  \ \ . $  [Initially, it "feels like" the second arrangement should be unreasonable...]

For the first arrangement, subtracting the first term from  the second and third produces $ \ a·(q - 1) \ = \ d \ \ , \ \ a·(q^2 - 1) \ = \ 2d \ \ . $  Taking $ \ a \neq 0 \ \ $ (otherwise, set $ \ N \ $ would only contain zeroes),   dividing the latter equation here by the former yields
$$ \frac{q^2 \ - \ 1}{q \ - \ 1} \ \ = \ \ q \ + \ 1 \ \ = \ \ \frac{2d}{d} \ \ = \ \ 2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ q \ = \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ q \ - \ 1 \ \ = \ \ \frac{d}{a} \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

This just gives us the "constant" sequence of terms you were concerned about (and which the stated conditions exclude).  But in fact, $ \ q = 1 \ $ isn't even permissible for this ratio.  So it turns out that the first arrangement of elements is the "incorrect one".

The seemingly unreasonable ordering leads to
$$ \ a·(q^2 - 1) \ = \ d \ \ , \ \ a·(q - 1) \ = \ 2d  $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{q^2 \ - \ 1}{q \ - \ 1} \ \ = \ \ q \ + \ 1 \ \ = \ \ \frac{d}{2d} \ \ = \ \ \frac12 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ q \ = \ -\frac12 $$  $$ \Rightarrow \ \ q^2 \ - \ 1 \ \ = \ \ -\frac34 \ \ = \ \ \frac{d}{a} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ d \ \ = \ \ -\frac34 · a \ \  . $$
We note that this leaves $ \ a \ $ unspecified, so there are an infinite number of such sequences possible.  The elements of the sets are thus
$$ \ \{ \ a \ \ , \ \  a \ - \ \frac34 a \ = \ \frac14 a \ = \ aq^2 \ \ , \ \ a \ - \ 2·\frac34 a \ = \ -\frac12 a \ = \ aq \ \} \ \ .  $$

$$ \ \ $$

[I also had an argument in which we could avoid the question of sequence ordering by looking at the *sum* of the elements, which gives us
$$ a·( 1 \ + \ q \ + \ q^2) \ \ = \ \ a \ + \ (a + d) \ + \ (a + 2d) \ \ = \ \ 3a \ + \ 3d $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ q^2 \ + \ q \ - \ \left(2 \ + \ 3·\frac{d}{a}\right) \ \ = \ \ 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ q \ \ = \ \ -\frac12 \ \pm \ \frac{\sqrt{1 \ + \ 4·\left(2 \ + \ 3·\frac{d}{a}\right)}}{2} \ \ = \ \ -\frac12 \ \pm \ \frac{\sqrt{ \ 9  +  \left(12·\frac{d}{a} \right)}}{2} $$ $$  = \ \ -\frac12 \ \pm \ \frac{3·\sqrt{ \ 1  +  \left(\frac{4d}{3a} \right)}}{2} \ \ .   $$
Setting the discriminant equal to zero gives us $ \ q \ = \ -\frac12 \ $ and $ \ 4·d \ = \ -3·a \ \ $ as above, but I didn't really see a satisfying explanation for doing so, other than "tidiness" of the result.]